# Background Color with Webpack and Symfony on Body

Tags: html, css, symfony, webpack

I'm setting Webpack on a new Project With Symfony 4. I'm following the doc, and I have a problem, I can't set a `background-color` to my `body`. But for no reason I can set the `background-color` to my H1 tag.

My base.twig.html is set like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>{% block title %}Welcome{% endblock %}</title>

    {% block stylesheets %}

        {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}


             <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/app.css">
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
{% block body %}
<h1>Welcome</h1>
{% endblock %}





{% block javascripts %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}           
        <script src="/build/runtime.js"></script>
        <script src="/build/app.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

On my console the JS is applied properly and the backgound color on my css is working fine on my H1 :

```
body{
    background-color: red;
}
h1{
    background: #0c5460;
}
```

I don't understand this mistake. If someone can tell me why. It could be great.

Comment: did you try with background:red;

Comment: yes also, it work on H1 tag but not on the body tag.

Comment: Maybe your CSS is overwritten? Did you check that? Try to include your CSS file after the `stylesheets` block, before the `</head>`